# A vertex added using addV() to gremlin-server is not visible when executing a subsequent traversal

Tags: java, gremlin, gremlin-server

I run official `gremlin-server` image in docker:

```
docker run -p 8182:8182 tinkerpop/gremlin-server:3.4.10
```

It starts on port 8182.

Then I execute the following code:

```
try (RemoteConnection connection = openConnection();
        GraphTraversalSource g = openRemoteTraversalSource(connection)) {

    g.V().addV("Test").property("a", "b").iterate();

    System.out.println(g.V().toList().size());
}
```

where

```
private DriverRemoteConnection openConnection() {
    return DriverRemoteConnection.using("localhost", 8182);
}

private GraphTraversalSource openRemoteTraversalSource(RemoteConnection connection) {
    return AnonymousTraversalSource.traversal().withRemote(connection);
}
```

I have `gremlin-driver` on classpath:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.tinkerpop</groupId>
    <artifactId>gremlin-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.10</version>
</dependency>
```

This code outputs 0. But as I added a vertex using `addV()` step, I expect to get one result.

I also tried to switch to `janusgraph/janusgraph:0.5.3` and get the same result, so I suppose the problem is with my code and not `gremlin-server`.

But what is missing? Why isn't the added vertex visible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line

```
g.V().addV("Test").property("a", "b").iterate();
```

needs to change to

```
g.addV("Test").property("a", "b").iterate();
```

Comment: Thanks, this works. But I wonder why have `g.V().addV()` available in the API if it does not add a vertex.

Comment: @RomanPuchkovskiy The `addV()` function adds an `AddVertexStep` to the traversal. Which creates a vertex for every incoming object. In your case there was zero incoming objects because `g.V()` did not yield any vertices. But if it yielded 3 vertices for example, then 3 new vertices would have been created by the `addV()` step.